# Foundation Navbar issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using `Foundation`. The `top-bar` (navigation) break out on some `787x676` resolution while resizing the window. I have cut/paste the code but issue was still there. Then i checked on `foundation` official website top-bar breaks on there website website too. I think there is some bug in foundation. Here is the [link](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/navigation.php)/screenshot. Is there any fix to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with fixing, it breaks when the size gets too small to hold all the content, so one could add a `min-width` to make sure it doesn't get smaller than that.

Example:

```
.top-bar {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

Or you could have it overflow, and just grow in height as content gets dropped below. To do so start with removing:

```
.top-bar {
    height: 47px !important;
}
```

That line makes the black bar stay as high as it is.

To swap to the mobile bar sooner, look for bits similar to `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` and increase the size to just above where it breaks, example `(max-width: 780px)`

Comment: well, adding min-width:800px fixes break issue but it effected responsiveness for smaller devices

Comment: @AamirShahzad then I suppose you got to make the bar grow in height like the rest explains.. ?

Comment: adding height is itself an issue... what i want is - it should switch to mobile version nav before breaking...